# I want price range between data through database in codeigniter pls find out

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to price range between data through database in codeigniter
problem is in my view what is `$content` it is in cart class how to load `$content`

**This is my controller file**

```
public function index()
{
     $this->load->model('sorts');
     $data['products'] = $this->sorts->sort_products1();
     $data['content'] = 'cart/products'; // Select our view file that will display our products
     $output_string = $this->load->view('range1', $data);
 }
```

**This is my model**

```
public function sort_products1()
{
    $this->db->select("p_id,p_img,p_name,p_qty,p_price");
    $this->db->where("p_price between 0 and 500 ");
    $query = $this->db->get('product');
    return $query->result_array();
    return $row;
}
```

**This is my view**

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="div1">
                <?php $this->view($content) ;?>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

//// in view $content  means

Comment: At least, that is error - 2 returns. will work only the 1st one. - `return $query->result_array();
            return $row;`

Comment: Don't understand what you are doing here, calling a view inside a view?

Comment: thats y am asking $content is a cart view how to load it

Comment: You would load your cart view in the controller, not the view...

Comment: @BrianRamsey you are not right - such aproach in view `$this->view(view_name)` is working

Answer (score -1):

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('sorts');
    $data['products'] = $this->sorts->sort_products1();

    $this->load->view('cart/products', $data);
}
```

At a guess, but you're not giving much to go on here?

Comment: kk but wr is the view file

Comment: how to add the view file